# How to relay packets for another network to that interface (not a gateway or bridge)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn

I have a server on two separate LANs: `enp3s0` (`10.0.0.5/24`) and `tun0` (`10.8.0.5/24`, openvpn client).  I've configured the gateways on both networks to forward packets addressed to the other network to this server.  How can I get this server to relay those packet to the other (correct) interface?  I've tried all of the `iptables` stuff I can find.

The server is running Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Comment: The routing table is the main factor, see `ip route` if you need more fancy things you can also use `ip rule` but that is unlikely to be needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate kernel forwarding?

```
echo 1> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Your box will act as a router, not as a workstation, and this behaviour is disabled by default, for security reasons!
Be sure to permit forward for only legit network ranges from both of your nets using iptables.

Comment: Yes, I activated kernel forwarding, but I never restarted the server. Maybe that's a problem?